# Как ужать 64 пикселя в 9?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Не понимаю, как в алгоритме HOG происходит построение 9-мерного вектора
Предположим, у нас есть матрица 8 × 8:

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 95
100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170
115 125 135 145 155 165 175 185
200 180 160 140 120 100 80 60
215 185 165 145 125 105 85 65
80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
85 75 65 55 45 35 25 15
```

Соответственно дальше эти 64 значения пикселя нужно ужать в 9-мерный вектор, но как точно это сделать, я не знаю.
Нужно ли считать направление по x и y, magnitude и orientation для каждого пикселя?
И пусть у нас есть вектор с ячейками от 0 до 160 с шагом 20:
0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160
Какие пиксели нужно заносить в эти ячейки?